# Inherit from functions(?)

Tags: python, python-3.x

**i have the 3 following separate python files in the same directory:**

```
with open('cds.txt', 'r') as d:
    dcontents = d.readlines()
dcontents = [d.strip() for d in dcontents]
dcontents = filter(None, dcontents)
cd_list = []

for item in dcontents:
    ac = create_cd(*item.split(';'))
    cd_list.append(ac)

cdcodelist = []
for i, cd in enumerate(cd_list):
    print('CD #{idx}: {c}, {n}, {g}, {p}, {a}, {y}'.format(idx=i+1, c=cd.code, n=cd.name, g=cd.genre,p=cd.pieces, a=cd.artist, y=cd.year))
    cdcodeforlist = cd.code
    cdcodelist.append(cdcodeforlist)
```

---

```
class create_cd:
    cost = 1.5
    rent = False
    def __init__(self, code, name, genre, pieces, artist, year):
        self.code = code
        self.name = name
        self.genre = genre
        self.pieces = pieces
        self.artist = artist
        self.year = year

    def __repr__(self):
        return("(%d,%s,%s,%d,%.2f,%s,%d)"%(self.code, self.name, self.genre, self.pieces, self.cost, self.artist, self.year))

    def setcode(self, code):
        self.code = code

    def setname(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def setyear(self, year):
        self.year = year

    def setcost(self, cost):
        self.cost = cost

    def setrent(self,rent):
        self.setrent = rent

    def setgenre(self, genre):
        self.genre = genre

    def setpieces(self, pieces):
        self.pieces = pieces

    def setartist(self, artist):
        self.artist = artist

    def getname(self):
        return self.name

    def getyear(self):
        return self.year

    def getcost(self):
        return self.cost

    def getgenre(self):
        return self.genre

    def getrent(self):
        return self.rent

    def getcode(self):
        return self.code

    def getartist(self):
        return self.artist

    def getpieces(self):
        return self.pieces
```

---

```
from cdclass import *
class cdvalidate(create_cd):

    def __repr__(self):
        return("(%d,%s,%s,%d,%.2f,%s,%d)"%(self.code, self.name, self.genre, self.pieces, self.cost, self.artist, self.year))

    def rentcd(self, days):
        setrent(True)
        return days*cost

    def searchcd(code):
        if rent == True:
            print("CD is rented")
        else:
            print("CD is not rented")
```

**Along with this text file:**

> 5412;Didn't It Rain;blues;12;Hugh Laurie;2000
>
> 5896;suddenly comes;alternative;8;closer;2016
>
> 875;nirvana;alternative;14;nirvana;2002

I am trying to create a program that imports the 3 cds and then have a text menu which gives the option to the user to rent a cd. I came up with the following code:

```
daystorentcd = input("\nEnter the amount of days you with to rent the cd for:")
usercode = str(input("Enter the code of the cd"))
if usercode in cdcodelist:
    cdvalidate.rentcd(daystorentcd)
else:
    print("\ninvalid code try again:")
```

Basically in the first file it creates a list with all the cds in *cd_list* and then uses the *cdcodelist* to store all the codes of the cds to validate them so if the user tries to enter a code that doesn't exist it shows an error.

Next, i send the code of the CD the user wishes to rent to the appropriate function, and ask for the *setrent* value of the cd with the same code to switch to True and return the total cost of the rental, so that the user later can choose to see which CDs are rented, but that is for another part of the menu, sadly it doesn't work, giving me the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Yiannis\Desktop\Test project\main.py", line 51, in 
>       cdvalidate.rentcd(daystorentcd) TypeError: rentcd() missing 1 required positional argument: 'days'

How do i resolve this? Where is the fault in my code?Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You shouldn't write dumb getters and setters, just access the attributes directly.

Comment: `cdvalidate` is a *class*, but `rentcd` is an instance method; you need to call it on an instance of `cdvalidate`. However without seeing how that final snippet fits in with anything else, it is impossible to tell you how to fix this.

Comment: @NilsWerner Could you elaborate please?Thanks.

Comment: @John.E that is basic OOP. It sounds like you would be better served by [a tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html).

Comment: @John.E Nils Werner is telling you to stop writing methods like `setname` and `getname`. Just use `self.name`. You don't need getters and setters in Python.